# How to resolve this integral $J = \int{\frac{2-\sin{x}}{2+\cos{x}}}dx$?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

$$J = \int{\frac{2-\sin{x}}{2+\cos{x}}}dx$$

I'm already try to do this step in below:
$$\overset{split}{=} \int{\frac{2}{2+\cos{x}}dx}+\int{\frac{d(\cos{x}+2)}{2+\cos{x}}} = \int{\frac{2}{1+2\cos^2{\frac{x}{2}}}dx} + \ln({2+\cos{x}})$$

Comment: Try Weierstrass substitution

Answer (score 3):

Note

$$\int{\frac{2}{1+2\cos^2{\frac{x}{2}}}dx}=\int{\frac{2\sec^2\frac x2}{\sec^2\frac x2+2}dx} 
 =4\int{\frac{d(\tan\frac x2)}{\tan^2\frac x2+3}dx} 
= \frac4{\sqrt3}\tan^{-1}\frac{\tan\frac x2}{\sqrt3}
$$

Answer (score 2):

This is a classical example where the parametric formulas help

$$dx=\frac{2}{1+t^2}dt$$

$$\sin x=\frac{2t}{1+t^2}$$

$$\cos x=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$$

Comment: thanks for your remind,  I know it, but I can't resolve it yet;

Answer (score 1):

We need to find $$J:=\int \frac{2-\sin(x)}{2+\cos(x)}\operatorname{dx}.$$
The answer is $$\boxed{J=\frac{4}{\sqrt{3}}\arctan\left(\frac{\tan(x/2)}{\sqrt{3}} \right)+\ln(\cos(x)+2)+C}$$

For solve $J$, we can use the substitution recommended by @Prime Mover.

Let, $\color{blue}{u=\tan(x/2)}$ so we have that $$\operatorname{du}=\frac{1}{2}\sec^{2}(x/2)\operatorname{dx}.$$

Then transform the integrand using the substitution recommended by @tommik, $$\sin(x)=\frac{2u}{u^{2}+1},$$ we can find that $$\cos(x)=\frac{1-u^{2}}{u^{2}+1},$$ and $$\operatorname{dx}=\frac{2}{u^{2}+1}\operatorname{du}.$$

Then, \begin{eqnarray}
J&=&\int \frac{2\left(2-\frac{2u}{u^{2}+1}\right)}{(u^{2}+1)\left(\frac{1-u^{2}}{u^{2}+1}+2 \right)}\operatorname{du}\\
&=&4\int \frac{u^{2}-u+1}{u^{4}+4u^{2}+3}\operatorname{du}\\
&=&2\int \frac{u+2}{u^{2}+3}\operatorname{du}-2\int \frac{u}{u^{2}+1}\operatorname{du}.
\end{eqnarray}
In the last part I used partial fractions, I'll let you fill in those details.

Since that, $$\frac{u+2}{u^{2}+3}=\frac{u}{u^{2}+3}+\frac{2}{u^{2}+3},$$so we have that $$J=2\int \frac{u}{u^{2}+3}\operatorname{du}+4\int \frac{1}{u^{2}+3}\operatorname{du}-2\int \frac{u}{u^{2}+1}\operatorname{du}.$$

The first integral is solved for change of variable $t_{1}:=u^{2}+3$, the second integral for change of variable $t_{2}:=\frac{u}{\sqrt{3}}$ and the third integral for change of variable $t_{3}:=u^{2}+1$.

Finally, return the variable changes and you will get $$J=\frac{4}{\sqrt{3}}\arctan\left(\frac{\tan(x/2)}{\sqrt{3}} \right)+\ln(\cos(x)+2)+C.$$

Comment: While this works, it's messy. I applaud OP's original strategy of splitting it into two separate integrations and taking advantage of the technique of the integral of a function under its derivative. That takes care of the sine without needing the Weierstrass substitution and its resulting heavy algebra requiring a quadratic factorisation and partial fractions and all.

Comment: @PrimeMover: To calculate $I:=\int \frac{2}{1+2\cos^{2}(x/2)}\operatorname{dx}$, you still have to go through the partial fractions. Note that $$I:=2\int \frac{1}{2\cos^{2}(x/2)+1}\operatorname{dx}=4\int \frac{1}{2\cos^{2}(t)+1}\operatorname{dt}=4\int \frac{\sec^{2}(t)}{2+\sec^{2}(t)}\operatorname{dt}=4\int \frac{1}{u^{2}+3}du$$where $u=\tan(t)$ and $t=x/2$.

Comment: Yes, I wasn't commenting on that aspect of it, I was commenting on splitting it up into $\displaystyle \int \dfrac {2 \mathrm d x} {2 + \cos x}$ and $\displaystyle \int \dfrac {-\sin x \mathrm d x} {2 + \cos x}$. You would *then* solve $\displaystyle \int \dfrac {2 \mathrm d x} {2 + \cos x}$ by Weierstrass and it is so much simpler than yours because you get $\displaystyle \int \dfrac {4 \mathrm d u} {3 + u^2}$ which is a standard arctan substitution

Answer (score 0):

To solve the $\displaystyle \int \dfrac 2 {2 + \cos x} \mathrm d x$, you may want to try the Weierstrass substitution $u = \tan \dfrac x 2$.

This will then yield a polynomial which simplifies significantly.

Comment: thanks for your help, but I can't simplifies it try my all effort yet.

Comment: @Loyio You will get $\displaystyle \int \dfrac {4 \mathrm d u} {3 + u^2}$ which yields to a standard arctan substitution (although it's a bit messy). See other answers for other ways of solving this.